# cache query unless model updated - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I have the following query:

```
def home
    @posts = Post.where(:isGroup => "public").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
end
```

I'd like to cache this query unless a new Post is added to the Post model.

When I use

```
expires_in 5.minutes, public: true
```

it caches the whole action instead of just the query (and messes up the whole page, since the results are the beginning of an infinite scroll, and the page has a login).

When i do:

```
cache "home_post", expires_in: 10.minutes do
     @posts = Post.where(:isGroup => "public").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
end
```

It does not seem to show any performance improvement and also does not update when a new post is added.

What would be the best way to just cache the query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cache the object as is `Rails.cache.write` and `Rails.cache.read` is what you need. More details are here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies#low-level-caching

To clean the cache everytime a post is created you can use `after_create` and then sweep the cache. For more see examples here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers

Comment: If I do this, I get an error (TypeError (can't dump anonymous class #<Module:0x007fde45a07c80>):                       Rails.cache.fetch("homepage_posts", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
      @posts = Post.where(:isGroup => "public").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
end

Comment: I would cache it this way `Rails.cache.write("homepage_posts", Post.where(:isGroup => "public").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20).all )`. `.all` caches the records and not just the active record instance. I would read it the same way too `Rails.cache.read('homepage_posts')`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could also `caches_action :home, :expires_in => 5.minutes, :layout => false, :public => true` and it'll just cache the query and data, and not the action's layout.